# PHP getting string in between two strings

Tags: php

So i have a file that is made up of different strings. An example would be:

```
$ADDR:1234 This Address;$NAME:Mike Steve,$NAME:Julia Steve;$IP:139.0.0.35
```

Now the problem is that it isn't delimited one thing, it is delimited by a `,` and a `;` and not every `,` means its a new field (I know it's horrible data).

The only thing it is delimited truly by is the fact that every field starts with a `$`.

I need to be able to store each field (everything after a `$` up to the next `$`) into a variable.

I have tried `substr` but i just cant seem to get it correct.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: explode by "$" char

Comment: Or regex with `g` flag.

Comment: `preg_match_all("(\$(?<key>\w+):(?<value>.*?)(?=[;,]\$|$))",$input,$matches);` should do the trick. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4pyqvA/1)

Comment: If it is parseable then you need to define the grammar properly. If the grammar cannot be defined, then it cannot be parsed. Based on your description you have not yet defined the grammar.

Comment: Is it several lines of these variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the explode function from php:

```
$arr = explode("$",$string);
```

In the $arr, you will have an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the $ sign.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of a large file with several lines you can make each variable an item in an array.
This will makes it easy to access the values later.

```
$str = '$ADDR:1234 This Address;$NAME:Mike Steve,$NAME:Julia Steve;$IP:139.0.0.35
        $ADDR:3456 This Address;$NAME:Steve,$NAME:Julia;$IP:139.0.0.36
        $ADDR:7890 This Address;$NAME:Mike,$NAME:Julia Steve;$IP:139.0.0.37';


Preg_match_all("/[$](\w+):(.*?)[\n|,|;]/", $str ."\n" , $m);
$i =-1;
Foreach($m[1] as $key => $val){
    If($val == 'ADDR') $i++; // replace '$ADDR' with what is first item on each line.
    $arr[$i][$val][] = $m[2][$key];
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/DBsfr